# vs2019 missing project properties selection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have installed vs2019 and created a JPG to TIF converter which works. I want to add a reference to a EXIF_Reader.dll - and there is no Project > Properties selection available. I need to use vs2019 as it implements a modified imports syntax so I am stuck. It is visible in all my other vs versions (2010,2015, 2017). What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK - Solved - I started VS2019 and then used the open folder on the splash page which loaded all the project files - and allowed editing,d building and debugging - What I should have done was 'Open Project' which enabled all of the menu options.